Serializing data with __getstate__ in Python
I'm trying to find out, what's wrong with my code, as its result is not what I expected. I simply tried to include the __getstate__ method to serialize data. This is my code:
class Examples_Classes_Singletons :

    _Instance = None

    def __new__(CLS):

        print(
            "[  DEBUG  ] Creating Class : {} | Line : {} | Module : {}".format(
                CLS, CLS.__firstlineno__, CLS.__module__
            )
        )

        if CLS._Instance is None:

            print(
                f"[ WARNING ] No Instance Found ! Creating Instance For Class '{CLS.__name__}' ..."
            )
            CLS._Instance = super().__new__(CLS)

            __Instance = f"<{CLS.__module__}.{CLS.__name__} object at {int( hex( id( CLS._Instance ) ) , 16 ):016X}>"
            print(f"[  DEBUG  ] Instance : {__Instance}")

        return CLS._Instance

    def __init__(Self):

        # print( Self.__class__.__mro__ == Self.__mro__ )
        # print( type( Self ) == Examples_Classes_Singletons )

        if "_initialized" in Self.__dict__ and Self._initialized:

            print(
                f"[  DEBUG  ] The Instance Of The Class '{Self.__class__.__name__}' Is Already Initialized !"
            )
            return

        print(f"[  DEBUG  ] Configuring Standard Variables ...")

        Self.Attribute_X = "TST1"  # Instance Variable
        Self.Attribute_Y = "TST2"  # Instance Variable

        Self._Protected_Attribute = {}
        Self._Cache = []

        # print( object.__getattribute__( Self , 'Attribute_X' ) )
        # print( super( ).__getattribute__( 'Attribute_X' ) )

        print(
            f"[  DEBUG  ] Initializing The Instance For Class '{Self.__class__.__name__}' ..."
        )

        Self._initialized = True

    def __getstate__(Self):

        State = Self.__dict__.copy()

        print(State)
        State["_Protected_Attribute"] = None
        if "_Cache" in State:
            del State["_Cache"]

        return State

    def __setstate__(Self, State):

        Self.__dict__.update(State)
        # Self._Cache = { }


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pass



T = Examples_Classes_Singletons()

T_Serialized = pickle.dumps(T)
T_Deserialized = pickle.loads(T_Serialized)

print(f"Serialized   : {T_Serialized}")
print(f"Deserialized : {T_Deserialized.__dict__}")

As you can see, I'm trying to set '_Protected_Attribute' to 'None' and remove '_Cache' before serializing the data.
Although I actually stuck to the guidelines, '_Cache' will not deleted. If I'm printing the data by:
print(f"Deserialized : {T_Deserialized.__dict__}")

the result is:
Deserialized : {'Attribute_X': 'TST1', 'Attribute_Y': 'TST2', '_Protected_Attribute': None, '_Cache': [], '_initialized': True}

'_Cache' is still available.
Is the code wrong, or did I misunderstand the syntax of __getstate__?

I have already narrowed it down a bit. Since ‘_Cache’ exists in ‘State’ before I execute ‘del State[’_Cache‘]’ & not afterwards, it must be due to ‘setstate’. I also suspect that it is due to the singleton, as a new object is created and then the variables are no longer defined because of my condition.

Try T is T_Deserialized to see what is going on. Hint: Your __new__ method is giving pickle.loads() your preexisting singleton instance.

Hi Dunes, thank you for you comment. T is T_Deserialized indeed is True what's wrong as the serialization creates a new object, or not ?
I have already found out that it is due to the singleton behaviour, if I completely remove the __new__ method, then I get the correct output :
Deserialized : {‘Attribute_X’: ‘TST1’, ‘Attribute_Y’: ‘TST2’, ‘_Protected_Attribute’: None, ‘_initialized’: True}
But I wonder, if the __new__ method, i.e. the singleton, is the problem, why is ProtectedAttribute set to None ?

Any ideas how to solve this problem while maintaining the singleton pattern ?

So you want pickles.loads() to create a new instance? Wouldn't that be in violation of your desire to have a singleton?

No, not at all. So __getstate__ does not work in connection with singletons ?

The pseudo-code for what pickles.loads() is doing is roughly:
# load values from data, which results in:
cls = Examples_Classes_Singletons
state = {'Attribute_X': 'TST1',
         'Attribute_Y': 'TST2',
         '_Protected_Attribute': None,
         '_initialized': True}

instance = cls.__new__(cls)
# NB. __init__() is NOT called
instance.__setstate__(state)
# ^-- Your implementation does self.__dict__.update(state).
# And this will set _Protected_Attribute to None
return instance

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but you need to make sure that __getstate__ and __setstate__ work in tandem to not overwrite any attributes you do not want overwritten.
Perhaps a better implementation of __setstate__ would be:
def __setstate__(self, state):
    if hasattr(self, '_Protected_Attribute'):
        # Protected attribute already initialised.
        # We are not interested in changing its value
        state.pop('_Protected_Attribute', None)
    self.__dict__.update(state)
    if not hasattr(self,'_Cache')
        self._Cache = []


Hey, thank you very much for your answer and the code you've provided. I will try to implent it iny my code and give you a feedback. Basicly, i don't want to achieve anything. I just want to understand the behavior of __getstate__ and how it works,
even with singeltons. :)
